# How to keep track of previous run times for a python script

Tags: python, sql, logging

I have a basic python program that accepts the directory of a sql script and a date (or list of dates) as command line arguments. The program executes the query in the sql script for each provided date. I'd like to be able to log the execution time of the sql query each time I run the program so I could use this data to estimate execution time given how many dates the user provided to run.

How can I store this information (query, date provided, execution time) in a way that the program can easily access it later? To clarify, I already know how to time the execution of each query but I don't know how/in what format to store this information.

Example:

```
$ python myscript /dir/of/script.sql -dates 20140101 20140102

script.sql    20140101    1m22s

script.sql    20140102    1m53s
```

I'm looking for a way to store this output information for many different sql scripts (which are located in different directories) and over a large number of executions (dates). I need to do this in such a way that I can get the information back into the program to estimate execution times for a given sql script given the execution times of its previous runs.

Comment: dict and pickle that data

Answer (score 0):

If the data doesn't have any value outside of an "installed" instance of the program, then install it locally.  If you want other executors of the python script to get estimates based on the run times of others executions (which might actually be a valid metric, since you're really timing the server here), you could store it in some sort of metrics collection table within the database.

In the case of the latter, I would probably just save all the timings in memory that were collected and save them to the database after all the scripts were run.